# Tag synonym proposals

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Since at this moment very few users have the sufficient reputations to even *propose* tag synonyms, and duplicate tags are already starting to be a problem, this is going to be a place for any member to point out which tag should be redirected where.

Post the redirections as answers, with any number of proposed redirections organized as a list. Entries shall be of the format:

- [tag](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) to [master-tag](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master-tag)
- [obscure-tag](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obscure-tag), [more-obscure-tag](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/more-obscure-tag),[other-tag](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/other-tag) to [non-obscure-tag](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-obscure-tag)

Add new ones as they come to the bottom of your lists. If we get too many answers and it becomes hard to track new propositions, once in a while myself or anyone with an edit questions privilege can add all new entries to the list at the end of this question.

Note to whomever will actually edit the tags: after you do, please edit the entries in the corresponding post which proposed the change to indicate which ones had been changed.

---

**List of proposed changes:**

- [bldc](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bldc) to [brushless-motor](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushless-motor) - DONE
- [fpv](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fpv) to [first-person-view](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-person-view) - DONE
- [airplane](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane) to [fixed-wing](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-wing) - Proposed
- [quadcopter-configuration](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadcopter-configuration) to [quadcopter](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadcopter) - Proposed

Answer (score 4):

Abbreviations still missing full versions for tags used more than once and my best guess:

(in order of volume)

- [lipo](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lipo) and (new) [lithium-polymer-batteries](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium-polymer-batteries) to [lipo-batteries](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lipo-batteries) ? I'm not sure that spelling it out here makes sense but we could make this a synonym, too. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [esc](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esc) to [electronic-speed-controllers](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-speed-controllers)
- [faa](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa) and (new) [federal-aviation-administration](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/federal-aviation-administration) to [united-states](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) (UK is just [united-kingdom](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) so it makes sense to have these be consistent
- [brushed](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushed) to [brushed-motors](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushed-motors) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [video](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) to [video-recording](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-recording) or [recording-video](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording-video) ? Thoughts? plain video seems rife for needing disambiguation.
- [t16](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t16) to [t16-transmitter](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t16-transmitter) or [jumper-t16-transmitter](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jumper-t16-transmitter) ? Using the company name with their products saves you needing to have a company tag separate from the product tag. That said, it also means you can't necessarily see all "jumper" questions together.

  - This would apply to any specific products, this one is an example.
- [diy](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) to [do-it-yourself](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/do-it-yourself)
- [tbs](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tbs) to [team-blacksheep](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-blacksheep) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [fpvcamera](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fpvcamera) to [fpv-cameras](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fpv-cameras) or [first-person-view-cameras](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-person-view-cameras) ? [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) ([fpv-cameras](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fpv-cameras))

Comment: okay, in order:
_lipo-batteries_ seems sensible. I'm not sure we need _lithium-polymer-batteries_. Stretching ESC out... we can do that if the latter exists already. 
FAA to united-states... seems like a good idea, though there might be drawbacks? Dunno.
brushed-motors: yes yes yes, do it.
video-recording is actually quite narrow; video covers fpv as well; Against. 
t16: I'd say to jumper-t16. A more generic "jumper" tag would also be very beneficial. Even better if SE had hierarchical tags, i.e. anything tagged t16 would automatically also show up under jumper.

Comment: DIY: I think this one is so known that there's no reason to expand. TBS: yes, totally. fpvcamera: probably just add a hyphen (and optionally the s)

Comment: @FlashCactus Video is a huge part of what drones do - recording, playback, formats, assembly, equipment (lenses/cameras/etc) - My concern about plain old "video" is that it'll be too much of a catch-all. Even right now, the three questions in the tag cover recording and building/assembly. When you think about tags, they need to generally capture interest of a point, so someone who likes to assemble video components will want a tag separate from someone who only uses their pre-fab drone for capturing video.

Comment: Let's discuss this in chat. (I've also raised some questions about the [tag:small-drones] tag there)

Comment: My thinking with f16-transmitter is that if someone just types in "transmitter" they'll see the option for f16-transmitter as well, letting them know that they can use a more specific tag. If it's just f16 or jumper-f16, they won't have that assist.

Comment: That's a good argument. Well, we can use the longest of these then, and synonymize the rest.
Does SE have any tag hierarchy at all? the best way would be to have anything that has jumper-t16 or whatever more narrow tag automatically _also_ be under transmitter, so that anyone filtering by the "transmitter" tag would have everything related to transmitters even if the original author only tagged by the model

Comment: *esc* to *electronic-speed-controllers*: Worth expanding to make it more accessible to people less familiar with the subject.; *faa* to *united-states*: This could go either way. Aviation.SE use *faa* (but not *united-kingdom*) ... perhaps some US users could offer insight?; *video* to *video-recording*: *video-recording* is probably a good alternative, it prevents future issues if another video subject comes up. (1/2)

Comment: *t16* to *jumper-t16-transmitter*: I think this change is a good format to use. It saves confusion down the line - other brands also use the t## format.; *diy* to *do-it-yourself*: I'm content with diy as I'm used to it and it is wodely used, but I have no objection to expanding it - probably worth it for consistency? (2/2)

Comment: @FlashCactus No tag hierarchy, no. :( I've been asking since before I got hired. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223400/can-we-group-constrain-and-add-heirarchy-to-tags/258678#258678 :D

Answer (score 2):

My own list of synonyms:

- [bldc](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bldc) to [brushless-motor](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushless-motor) (suggested)
- [fpv](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fpv) to [first-person-view](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-person-view) (suggested)
- [airplane](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane) to [fixed-wing](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-wing)

Comment: Done, I’ve suggested the changes. I think I’ve got them the right way round. If I haven’t, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I've proposed:

- [quadcopter-configuration](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadcopter-configuration) to [quadcopter](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadcopter)
- [airplane](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplane) to [fixed-wing](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-wing)

Users can browse and vote on proposed tags [here](https://drones.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) - but I think you can only see/vote on them if you have a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag.

Comment: Before I merge airplane with fixed-wing, can you help me understand it? Are all airplanes fixed wings?

Comment: @Catija I wouldn't be surprised if there were exceptions, but airplane/aeroplane seems to be widely defined and used as synonymous fixed-wing - such as by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/airplane) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airplane).